# Como posso fazer para que minha GridView as imagens tenham tamanhos diferentes

Tags: android, android-studio

Gostaria que a gridview fica-se assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

A maneira que eu recomendo é usar o [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) junto com um [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html).

Você terá algo como:

```
RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredLayoutManager =
        new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

recycler.setLayoutManager(staggeredLayoutManager);
```

Onde o primeiro parâmetro do `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` é o número de colunas.

É claro que você pode configurar a estratégia para preenchimento dos "gaps".

Ai você pode usar o método `setGapStrategy` com uma dessas constantes:

```
GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS - Não tem documentação, mas ele provavelmente move os itens para ocupar os espaços
GAP_HANDLING_LAZY - Só ocupa os gaps quando houver scroll
GAP_HANDLING_NONE - Não faz nada, deixa o gap
```

Outra questão são os `spans`, no `LayoutParams` do item da lista, você pode definir se o item usa todos os `spans` ou não, isso é, definir se ele ocupa a linha inteira ou não.

Ai é só usar dentro do seu `Adapter` o `LayoutParams.setFullSpan(boolean)`.

É claro que terá que implementar um `RecyclerView.Adapter`, que é um pouco diferente de implementer um `BaseAdapter` por exemplo.

Para ver mais detalhes recomendo essas fontes:

- http://pt.slideshare.net/devunwired/mastering-recyclerview-layouts
- http://www.thiengo.com.br/recyclerview-material-design-android-parte-2
- https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html